# HashingTF not giving unique indices

Tags: java, apache-spark, svd, lsa

i am implementing Latent Semantic Analysis LSA, using eclipse Mars, java 8, and spark spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar 
I passed the documents as tokens , then got SVD and so on

```
   HashingTF hf = new HashingTF(hashingTFSize);
    JavaRDD<Vector> ArticlesAsV = hf.transform(articles.map(x->x.tokens));
  JavaRDD<Vector> ArticlesTFIDF = idf.fit(ArticlesAsV).transform(ArticlesAsV);
RowMatrix matTFIDF = new RowMatrix(ArticlesTFIDF.rdd());
   double rCond= 1.0E-9d;
    int k = 50;
    SingularValueDecomposition<RowMatrix, Matrix> svd =  matTFIDF.computeSVD(k, true, rCond);
```

every thing works perfectly, except for one, that is when i try to get the indices of the terms from the hashingTF

```
int index = hf.indexOf(term);
```

i found that there are many terms that have the same index,those are some i got

0  :  Term
1  :  all
1  :  next
2  :  tt
3  :  the
7  :  document
9  :  such
9  :  matrix
11  :  document
11  :  about
11  :  each
12  :  function
12  :  chance
14  :  this
14  :  provides
means that, when i try to get the vector of  term to something with it, i may get the vector of another one with the same index, i did it after lemmatization and removing the stop word, but still got the same error, is there anything that i missed, or an error with the components (e.g MLip) that need to be updated ; how can i keep a unique for each term.

Answer (score 2):

Spark class [HashingTF](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF) 
utilizes the [hashing trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing).

> A raw feature is mapped into an index (term) by applying a hash
>   function. Then term frequencies are calculated based on the mapped
>   indices. This approach avoids the need to compute a global
>   term-to-index map, which can be expensive for a large corpus, but it
>   suffers from potential hash collisions, where different raw features
>   may become the same term after hashing. To reduce the chance of
>   collision, we can increase the target feature dimension, i.e., the
>   number of buckets of the hash table. The default feature dimension is 2^20=1,048,576.

**So groups of terms can have the same index.**

Relative to the comments below, if you need of all terms you can use **CountVectorizer** instead of **HashingTF**. 
CountVectorizer can also be used to get term frequency vectors.
To use [CountVectorizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.html) and subsequently [IDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/IDF.html) 
you must use DataFrame instead of JavaRDD, because CountVectorizer is supported only in **ml** package.

This is an example of DataFrame with columns **id** and **words**:

```
id | words
---|----------  
0  | Array("word1", "word2", "word3")  
1  | Array("word1", "word2", "word2", "word3", "word1")
```

So If you translate **articles** JavaRDD to DataFrame with columns **id** and **words** where each row is a bag of words from a sentence or document, you can compute **TfIdf** with a code like this:

```
CountVectorizerModel cvModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
  .setVocabSize(100000) // <-- Specify the Max size of the vocabulary.
  .setMinDF(2) // Specifies the minimum number of different documents a term must appear in to be included in the vocabulary.
  .fit(df); 

  DataFrame featurizedData = cvModel.transform(articles);

  IDF idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features");
  IDFModel idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData);
```

Comment: I got it,  i set the size to the max ()of 1048576, and it worked  for 14696 unique terms and i got 14453 unique indicies missing 243 terms, but will it do the same for 671333 unique terms. since i have a bigger size of data to test on, will it miss a many terms??

Comment: for 671333 i got 489302, missing 185031,   still not good, i need an index for every term, the missing terms could be important ones, any way to work it around???

Comment: You could only enlarge the max size more than 1048576 using the constructor **HashingTF(numFeatures: Int)** and hope that It generates few collision. Even If  HashingTF missing many terms there are [two reasons It still works](http://blog.someben.com/2013/01/hashing-lang/)

Comment: but, if i am going to find similarities between a new short doc with few words, i think it will affect the results, with new large docs with many words we can neglect it, but i am working on short ones, do you think it will get acceptable results ??(again: input docs are large, test docs are short)

Comment: A possible Work Around is to use [CountVectorizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#countvectorizer) instead of HashingTF. CountVectorizer can also be used to get term frequency vectors.

Comment: can i use CountVectorizer to computer tfidf. For the hashingTF i used this code                          JavaRDD<Vector> ArticlesAsV = hf.transform(articles.map(x->x.tokens));
  IDF idf = new IDF();
  JavaRDD<Vector> ArticlesTFIDF = idf.fit(ArticlesAsV).transform(ArticlesAsV);

Comment: I updated the answer because the comment's characters are limitated.

Comment: @ Umberto. thank you, but i wounder if it can support 400K of documents, and 670K of terms ??

Comment: @Yas It depends your Spark cluster's size. Anyway Spark's operators spill data to disk if it does not fit in memory, allowing it to run well on any sized data.

Comment: @ Umberto. thanks, and yes, i think it will work, but slower for a small cluster